# Columnspan Widget Throwing Off Columns

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I'm having trouble getting my first "None" checkbox widget where I want it. Here is a link to a screenshot.

[image]

I'm trying to get the "None" checkbox widget to be directly to the right of the Entry widget. The bottom rows containing spinbox widgets are contained within a LabelFrame widget located at row=7, column=2 that has a columnspan of 2. My first checkbox widget is located at row=5, column=3 with sticky='w'. Why then isn't it up against the Entry widget at row=5, column=2 since I gave the LabelFrame a columnspan of 2?

Here is my code:

```
tk.Label(GUI, text='label 1').grid(row=0, sticky='w')
tk.Label(GUI, text='label 2').grid(row=1, sticky='w')
tk.Label(GUI, text='label 3').grid(row=2, sticky='w')
tk.Label(GUI, text='label 4').grid(row=3, sticky='w')
tk.Label(GUI, text='label 5').grid(row=4, sticky='w')
tk.Label(GUI, text='label 6').grid(row=5, sticky='w')
tk.Label(GUI, text='label 7').grid(row=6, sticky='w')
tk.Label(GUI, text='label 8').grid(row=7, sticky='w')
tk.Label(GUI, text='label 9').grid(row=8, sticky='w')

tk.Label(GUI, text='$').grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w')
tk.Label(GUI, text='$').grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='w')
tk.Label(GUI, text='$').grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='w')

tk.Label(GUI, text='9999').grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='w')

input1 = tk.Entry(GUI, width=10)
input2 = tk.Entry(GUI, width=10)
input3 = tk.Entry(GUI, width=10)
button_input = tk.Checkbutton(GUI, text='None')
input5 = tk.Entry(GUI, width=10)

date_field = tk.LabelFrame(GUI)
scheduled_start_month_input = tk.Spinbox(date_field, from_=1, to=12, width=2)
scheduled_start_day_input = tk.Spinbox(date_field, from_=1, to=31, width=2)
scheduled_start_year_input = tk.Spinbox(date_field, from_=2018, to=2025, width=4)
scheduled_start_hour_input = tk.Spinbox(date_field, from_=0, to=23, width=2)
scheduled_start_minute_input = tk.Spinbox(date_field, from_=0, to=59, width=2)
start_on_launch_option = tk.Checkbutton(date_field, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, text='On Launch')
scheduled_stop_month_input = tk.Spinbox(date_field, from_=1, to=12, width=2)
scheduled_stop_day_input = tk.Spinbox(date_field, from_=1, to=31, width=2)
scheduled_stop_year_input = tk.Spinbox(date_field, from_=2018, to=2025, width=4)
scheduled_stop_hour_input = tk.Spinbox(date_field, from_=0, to=23, width=2)
scheduled_stop_minute_input = tk.Spinbox(date_field, from_=0, to=59, width=2)
scheduled_stop_none = tk.Checkbutton(date_field, onvalue=True, offvalue=False, text='None')


input1.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='w')
input2.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='w')
input3.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky='w')
button_input.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky='w')
input5.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky='w')

date_field.grid(row=7, column=2, rowspan=2, columnspan=2, sticky='w')
scheduled_start_month_input.grid(column=0)
tk.Label(date_field, text='/').grid(column=1, row=0)
scheduled_start_day_input.grid(column=2, row=0)
tk.Label(date_field, text='/').grid(column=3, row=0)
scheduled_start_year_input.grid(column=4, row=0)
tk.Label(date_field, text=' ').grid(column=5, row=0)
scheduled_start_hour_input.grid(column=6, row=0)
tk.Label(date_field, text=':').grid(column=7, row=0)
scheduled_start_minute_input.grid(column=8, row=0)
start_on_launch_option.grid(row=0, column=9)

scheduled_stop_month_input.grid(column=0)
tk.Label(date_field, text='/').grid(column=1, row=1)
scheduled_stop_day_input.grid(column=2, row=1)
tk.Label(date_field, text='/').grid(column=3, row=1)
scheduled_stop_year_input.grid(column=4, row=1)
tk.Label(date_field, text=' ').grid(column=5, row=1)
scheduled_stop_hour_input.grid(column=6, row=1)
tk.Label(date_field, text=':').grid(column=7, row=1)
scheduled_stop_minute_input.grid(column=8, row=1)
scheduled_stop_none.grid(column=9, row=1, sticky='w')

tk.Button(GUI, text='Launch').grid(row=9, sticky='w')

GUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: Layout problems are almost always much, much easier to debug when all of the layout code is grouped together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the 2nd column is wider than you think it is. To see it, change the line where you add the input widget to the grid so that it looks like this:

```
input3.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky='ew')
```

You'll see that the checkbutton is in fact as far left as it can go, and it is the column to its left that is responsible for all of the extra space.

The reason is because the `datefield` widget spans two columns, but those two columns aren't wide enough to hold the datefield. `grid` has to add extra space to the columns so that the widget will fit.

If you want the second column to stay a fixed size and have column 3 to be the one that grows and shrinks, you have to give column 3 a non-zero weight so that `grid` can allocate all extra space to that column.

You can do that by adding this line of code somewhere:

```
GUI.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
```

Another solution would be to add the weight to an invisible column 4, and then have `datefield` span three columns instead of two. That will cause columns 2 and 3 to retain their natural size, and any extra space would be given to an empty column.

```
GUI.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
date_field.grid(row=7, column=2, rowspan=2, columnspan=3, sticky='w')
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I just started using tkinter on Monday and I'm struggling in finding information as the documentation isn't very thorough.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code:

```
GUI.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
```

It means that column 3 would occupy all the place it can get. Your/default weight is 0. <strike>and that means Checkbutton instance is wide just as "None" text is, so sticky w equals sticky e equals sticky we or wens. If you set the weight to 1 then your sticky argument actually takes place.</strike>

Comment: Your explanation isn't correct even though your code suggestion works. The "sticky" option is working just fine. The problem isn't that the column needs to be wider for the "sticky" to work, it's that the column to its left is wider than the entry widget it contains. You can see that by taking the original code and using a sticky of "ew" for the entry widget.

Comment: I edited and changed that disputable "column 3" into "Checkbutton instance". The point is that without grid_columnconfigure Checkbutton left/x starts on a half the space spinboxes occupy.

Comment: The description is still not accurate. The "sticky" attribute on that column is working just fine. The problem isn't the whitespace to the left of the checkbutton, it's the whitespace to the right of the column to its left.